# No create XHTML option in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf-2, xhtml, facelets

I am using Eclipse Kepler,version=4.3.0(tried with version=3.7.0 also).I tried using javax.faces-2.2.5.jar and javax.faces-2.2.1.jar.

Steps that i am following :
File -> New -> Dynamic Web Project -> Dynamic web module version - 2.5(tried with 3.0 also),Configuration - JavaServerFaces v1.2Project ->  Next -> Next -> Next -> JSF implementation Library - Added javax.faces-2.2.5.jar -> Finish.

After the project got created :
Right Click on project name -> Properties -> Project facets : Dynamic Web Module - 2.5
Java - 1.5
Javascript - 1.0
Java Server faces - 1.2

I even did : Window > Preferences > General > Content Types > Text > JSP and then add *.xhtml as file association and set default encoding to UTF-8.

Also, did Help -> Check for updates and updated eclipse.

After doing all this , when i do Right Click on Web Content ->  New ,there is no option for creating XHTML pages.

Please suggest if i am missing something.

Comment: apart from your question, you are using a JSF 1.2 Facet for JSF 2.2

Comment: @MicheleMariotti :  I have tried with every permutation, combination but not getting XHTML option. I thought i am missing some plugin or jar or something.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answering my own question as i found the solution :

I am now getting the option to create XHTML pages.
Steps that i followed :

Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> Find(Jboss) -> Jboss tools(Kepler)4.1.1 Final.
After installing this, i am getting the option to create XHTML pages.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for create xhtml option and found this post. Thanks. 
Installing JBoss Tools does give the option to create xhtml pages. 
Alternatively, you can also use the "New-->File" option in eclipse to create a new file and give it xhtml extension. This will not require you to install JBoss tools in eclipse.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Just noticed the question is from 2014. So I hope this helps some one new to JSF just like me.

Answer (score 0):

Go back and remove that content type association. Then, for JavaServer Faces pages, use the New JSP wizard, picking one of the JSF templates and giving it the filename extension you want.

Comment: Why am i not getting New -> XHTML option ?

Comment: Because there's no such wizard. If you go to the File menu and New->Other, you'll see all of the available wizards.

Answer (score 0):

After installing a new version of Eclipse, the create XHTML file option wasn't where I remembered it.  I had already installed JBoss Tools.  Under this version (the March 2019 Eclipse with JBoss Tools added), the option is found under `File -> New -> Other -> JBoss Tools Web -> XHTML Page`.

After you select `File -> New -> Other`, the wizard that shows includes a "type filter text" box.  If you enter XHTML there, it will show the relevant option and where it is found.  If I had noticed that first, that would have been easier than Googling and would have produced the correct answer.  Presumably that will continue to work even after future updates so long as there is some XHTML wizard available.

Answer (score 0):

As MaksSki said, there is no need to download a tool from marketplace.

Right click on the folder you wish to create the file in:
New -> HTML -> (enter-file-name.xhtml) -> Next -> Select from one of the many templates (example - New Facelet Composition Page).
[image: Eclipse Screenshot - New -> HTML]

[image: Eclipse Settings Screenshot of - Selecting XHTML Template]

To edit the templates use: Settings -> Web -> HTML Files -> Editor -> Templates
[image: Eclipse Settings Screenshot of - Settings -> Web -> HTML Files -> Editor -> Templates]

Answer (score -2):

Do `Folder` -> `New` -> `Other` -> `General` -> `File`. Then write the file name, e.g `index.xhtml`. Then click `Finish`.

You don't need to download another tool to create a .xhtml file in Eclipse IDE. My Eclipse version is of 2022 year.